The filter 'does not match regex' match type not working in GA4 API
I am using ga4 api and following is the code which is throwing error:

'AttributeError: DOES_NOT_MATCH_REGEX'
The same filter works on GA analaytics webpage but not here.

def run_ga4_report(property_id, property_name):
    # Build the dimension filter to exclude matching sessionSourceMedium values
    filter_expression = FilterExpression(
        filter=Filter(
            field_name="sessionSourceMedium",
            string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(
                # match_type=Filter.StringFilter.MatchType.FULL_REGEXP,
                match_type=Filter.StringFilter.MatchType.DOES_NOT_MATCH_REGEX,
                value=filter_pattern
            )
        )
    )

    # Build the request
    request = RunReportRequest(
        property=f"properties/{property_id}",
        date_ranges=[
            {"start_date": DATE_RANGE_START, "end_date": DATE_RANGE_END}
        ],
        dimensions=[{"name": dim} for dim in dimensions_input],
        metrics=[{"name": metric} for metric in metrics_input],
        dimension_filter=filter_expression  # Apply filter on sessionSourceMedium
    )
    
    # Execute the GA4 API request
    try:
        response = client.run_report(request)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error fetching data from GA4 API for property {property_name} (ID: {property_id}): {e}")
        return None

Expecting Data but it throws error. It works fine if filter is FULL_REGEXP

If FULL_REGEXP works for your case, you can invert the filter logic in your code to simulate DOES_NOT_MATCH_REGEX. Specifically, you can exclude values that match the regular expression by using a NOT logical expression.. It will work (I ve used this way to get top popular 1000 pages without page not found / 404 pages in my case)
filter_expression = FilterExpression(
    not_expression=FilterExpression(
        filter=Filter(
            field_name="sessionSourceMedium",
            string_filter=Filter.StringFilter(
                match_type=Filter.StringFilter.MatchType.FULL_REGEXP,
                value=filter_pattern
            )
        )
    )
)


I did use it, but there is data mismatch between data pulled by this and ga4 UI interface
